# Equivalence testing with p-values

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, equivalence

I have two datasets and I want to determine whether they are statistically equivalent.

Can I use a hypothesis test, obtain a p-value, and say that if p > 0.05, then the two datasets are statistically equivalent with 95% confidence?

If the p-value is > 0.01, can I say the two datasets are statistically equivalent with 99% confidence?

Comment: This depends on how you frame the null hypothesis.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Could you give an example on how you'd need to frame the null hypothesis to make my reasoning correct?

Comment: For equivalence the traditional null and alternative are reversed,  The null hypothesis would be that the difference of the two parameters is NOT zero. Then if you reject the null hypothesis you can conclude equivalence. The way you framed it you would not reject the null hypothesis of equivalence. But that is not the same as accepting it. Blackwelder's paper on reversing the null and alternative hypotheses deals with both trying to show non-inferiority or equivalence.

Comment: You can't really say such a thing "with $100(1-\alpha)\%$ confidence"; that's not really accurate either in the ordinary meaning of confidence nor in the statistical sense of the word.

Answer (score 2):

As Michael Chernick stated, it will depend on your null hypothesis, which could be any statement about the value of a parameter. Often this parameter is the mean. However, the similarity of one parameter is typically not enough to determine whether two datasets have substantial similarity. If you want to use NHST (null hypothesis significance testing) you could use a distributional test, for example, a Kolmogorov–Smirnov test. This test will give you a p-value with the null hypothesis that the two datasets are not different. The problem with such tests is that their power is low for small sample sizes, while for large samples sizes they pick up on differences that are not *practically* important (i.e. when comparing a Poisson distribution with large mean/variance to its normal approximation). So looking at the mean, variance, and possibility higher moments of the datasets might also be informative.